# Django: Prefetch on through table with filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-prefetch-related

I have the following models:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through="Membership")

class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="membership")
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="membership")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
```

The is_active on membership denotes whether a person is still a part of the group. I am trying to query groups and prefetch all active members.
The script that I am using is

```py
from sample.models import Person, Group
from django.db.models import Prefetch
from django.db import connection, reset_queries
reset_queries()
qs = Group.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "members", queryset=Person.objects.filter(membership__is_active=True),
    )
)
print(list(qs.all()))
print(len(connection.queries)) # Should be two queries
```

However, the query that gets generated for the prefetch is

```sql
SELECT 
  ("sample_membership"."group_id") AS "_prefetch_related_val_group_id", 
  "sample_person"."id", 
  "sample_person"."name" 
FROM 
  "sample_person" INNER JOIN "sample_membership" ON ( "sample_person"."id" = "sample_membership"."person_id")
  INNER JOIN "sample_membership" T3 ON ( "sample_person"."id" = T3."person_id") 
WHERE "sample_membership"."is_active" AND T3."group_id" IN (1, 2)
```

There are two joins on sample_membership and only one of them has the `is_active` filter. (This is an abstracted version of what I am trying to solve - but the essence remains the same - having the ability to add filters on the m2m relationship when prefetch_related is used)

Edit:
I have a `serializers.py` file as

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Person, Group
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'

class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = PersonSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = '__all__'
```

In the output of the group serializer, I am trying to get members with an active membership.
A sample script to test out the serializer output would be

```py
from sample.models import Person, Group, Membership
from sample.serializers import GroupSerializer
from django.db.models import Prefetch
from django.db import connection, reset_queries
reset_queries()
qs = Group.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "membership",
      queryset=Membership.objects.filter(is_active=True).select_related("person"),
    )
)
for q in list(qs.all()):
    gs = GroupSerializer()
    gs.to_representation(instance=q)
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the `Membership` instances and then select the related `Person` instances instead of filtering the `Person` instances in the queryset.

edit: we could use `anotate` for the serializer

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
from django.db.models.functions import ArrayAgg
from sample.models import Person, Group, Membership
from django.db.models import Q

# Reset queries
from django.db import connection, reset_queries
reset_queries()

# Define the prefetch queryset
prefetch_qs = Membership.objects.filter(is_active=True).select_related("person")

# Annotate the Group queryset with the active members
qs = Group.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch("membership_set", queryset=prefetch_qs, to_attr="active_memberships")
).annotate(
    active_member_names=ArrayAgg("membership_set__person__name", filter=Q(membership_set__is_active=True))
)

# Fetch the groups
groups = list(qs.all())

# Print results
print(groups)
print(len(connection.queries))
print(connection.queries[-2].values())
print(connection.queries[-1].values())

for group in groups:
    print(f"Active members in group {group.name}:")
    print(", ".join(group.active_member_names))
```

Comment: is there a way to have the members available on the top queryset so that this can be used directly in a serializer ?

Comment: I updated the annotation to be `active_members = ArrayAgg("membership__person", filter=Q(membership__is_active=True))`  and the serializer to have `members = PersonSerializer(many=True, source="active_members")`
However, the following snippet still does not work. `for q in list(qs.all()):
    gs = GroupSerializer()
    gs.to_representation(instance=q)`